# What shall I do on the visa form question that doesn't fit to me?

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia

When I fill Australia visa form I got a question that ask me "Other ways you spell your name". Unfortunately I have no other way so I think it's better to leave it blank at the same time I fell it must be filled something and I got idea to say none but on the instruction of the form there is nothing that say put none on question that doesn't fit to you, so what shall I do?

Comment: Draw a line or put "n/"a (for not applicable) if you feel you must do something.

Comment: @RoboKaren - would that not be a "n/a" ;-)

Answer (score 10):

**Leave it blank**, which is what I imagine the vast majority of people filling the form will do.  If it's a paper form, drawing a line through the box also works.

Writing "NONE" or "N/A" is also acceptable, but runs a tiny risk of some dimwitted computer or bureaucrat actually thinking your name is None.  (See also: [Mr. Null](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/).)